# Returning correct value from array in Form Select

Tags: laravel

Just having trouble trying to retrieve the correct value from form::select upon form submit.

I am passing in an array (which contains full_name and ID). The form is displaying the correct information, however, when I return the value from form submit (e.g. if the coach changes the current value/player to new Name), I am getting back the form array ID, not the username ID I am trying to get. Code below

In controller:

```
    $ids = array($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5, $p6, $p7, $p8, $p9, $p10, $p11, $p12, $p13, $p14, $p15, $p16);
    $ids_ordered = implode(',', $ids);

    $player= DB::table('players')
        ->whereIn('id', $ids)
        ->selectRaw('id, CONCAT(fname," ",lname) as full_name')
        ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $ids_ordered)"))
        //->pluck('id' ,'full_name') //Only returning  ONE value - not both?
        ->get()
        ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
          return [$i->id => $i->full_name.' ('.$i->id.')'];
        });

    $player=collect([$player])->flatten();
```

Note: I need to get the 16 x IDs in the correct order as it is a sports team selection form. This part is working. I also tried using Pluck, but for some reaon could only return ONE value (e.g. full_name OR ID) - not both. So I changed to mapWithKeys.

In form/view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('capt','Team Captain for Matchcard') !!}
        {!! Form::select('capt', $played, null, ['placeholder' => $played[0] ,'class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    </div>
```

There are 16 fields in the form as per above. the placeholder is the current value (currently selected team player). The coach can CHANGE from the drop-down ($played array).

The form displays perfectly. So whats happening, lets say the coach changes the capt field above (current player id is 17 but $played array value is 0). If we change/select a new player from the drop down (e.g. id 25 which may be 4th name in the drop list - hence array value [3] ) - my return on submit (back in controller) is displaying 3 and I want 25 (the actual player ID of the desired name/player from the Players table).

Appreciate if someone can help me get the new ID in this scenario... much appreciated and thanks in advance.

PS: I am using Laravel 5.4

Array display:

[image]

Using example above, if I change the capt field in form select to Corry Allsop (id 12), the form is returning 2 (3rd name in array)

Comment: using pluck would result in an array with id as the index and full_name as the value. so u might want to get use the index to get the value of id

Comment: Thanks Zam. My issue using pluck, if I return $player (before calling view) - I can only display ONE value, not both. I may have incorrect pluck syntax - but can only get full_name OR id - not both in the raw array. The alt method i used above IS returning the correct array inc both full_name and id - its just I cant get the newly selected player ID back from the form upon submission - instead, I get back the NEW ARRAY order ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct way to get `$played` from database using pluck

```
$player= DB::table('players')
        ->whereIn('id', $ids)
        ->selectRaw('id, CONCAT(fname," ",lname) as full_name')
        ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $ids_ordered)"))
        ->pluck('full_name' ,'id')
```

pluck second parameter will be array key and the first is value

```
//view
{{ Form::select('capt', $played, null) }}
```

Edit:

remove this line `$player=collect([$player])->flatten();`. 
The flatten method flattens a multi-dimensional collection into a single dimension. that's why the id as key replaced by array key (start from 0)

Edit 2:

display current player

```
//controller
return view('grades.matchcard.edit', ['ids' => $ids, played' => $player, 'matchcards' => $data, 'rounds' => $data1, 'mid' => $mcid, 'gstat' => $gstat, 'Rplayers' => $Rplayers]);

//view
{{ Form::select('capt', $played, $ids[0], ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

{{ Form::select('capt', $played, $ids[1], ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Comment: Thanks bhill... similar to my notes to Zam above - I need to get the ID back from the submission instead of the order in array. If I select the forth name in the drop down which is 3 in the array order, when I $x = $request->capt; I return 3 instead of the ID of that name (from original array) which for argument sake should be id of 25. 

PS: With the pluck method, if I return $player after the query, should I see the ID as well as the name? as I only see the full_name in my instance. thanks again.

Comment: sorry I misreading. how you get the `$played`? on your question you just provide how to get `$player`

Comment: return view('grades.matchcard.edit', ['played' => $player, 'matchcards' => $data, 'rounds'  => $data1, 'mid' => $mcid, 'gstat' => $gstat, 'Rplayers' => $Rplayers]);

Comment: still using pluck method and remove this line `$player=collect([$player])->flatten();` what is the data result?

Comment: It returns the ID -> {"17":"Steven Graham","1":"David Rattcliffe"... Your a star!! I got an undefined 0 error due to my placeholder ( $player[0] ..)

How do I now display the first record (old $player[0])..?

Note, if I temp remove placeholder - IT IS returning the correct ID :)

Comment: I need to display the CURRENT value in order (player 1 to player 16). If I remove placeholder, I get the first value (Steven Graham) is ALL displayed values.... the order of the actual array IS correct - but need to display the placeholder AS current player in that order... Thats why I had $played[0] for player 1, $played[1] for player 2 and so forth...

Comment: Just to clarify above: 2 of the 16 examples in form:

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('capt','Team Captain for Matchcard') !!}
            {!! Form::select('capt', $played, null, ['placeholder' => $played[0], 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('gk','GK for Matchcard') !!}
            {!! Form::select('gk', $played, null, ['placeholder' => $played[1], 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

Comment: did you save the id from capt, gk and others? you can pass it as third parameter in Form::select

Comment: ?? sorry not sure what you mean... 

in the original array of ids - thats the correct player IDs and in the correct order - $p1 to $p16. $p1 is the captain, $p2 is the gk, $p3 - $p16 are players 3 to 16 in the team. 

I need to display the current selected players in above order (which was working in original form array) and allow the coach to change players as needed (e.g. changing current Steven Graham (id of 17) with another player Corry Allsop (id of 12). 

After making changes to the pluck based on your suggestion, the form submission IS now returning the correct ID of the player.

Comment: Just need to now (last issue) display the CURRENT player in each of the 16 x form select fields (placeholder).